# Chrome CSS Local Overrides instead of !important for Chrome Extension

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I originally made a Chrome Extension that overrides some of the margins, padding, and font size CSS on a website using !important. It was pretty cumbersome and a bit painful to update since the website is pretty complex.

I then discovered Local Overrides in the Chrome Developer Tools which allows me to make all my edits in Chrome, see the changes, and a CSS file is generated. Is there a good way to take the CSS file, build it into a Chrome Extension, and load it independently of the Chrome Developer Tools?

Comment: There's no API for extensions to use the Local Overrides. Extensions can inject a CSS file into the page either [declaratively in manifest.json](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) or via chrome.tabs.insertCSS or by creating a standard DOM `link` element and assigning its href to a URL of the css file exposed via [web_accessible_resources](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources).

Comment: @wOxxOm I'm not asking for an API specifically. Simply asking how to make a Chrome extension to take a CSS file and override the CSS that is loaded by a page without using !important. I've tried most of the things described in the links provided, but have not had any luck.

Comment: The only methods to inject CSS are described in my comment above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to figure this out by injecting the CSS file from Developer Tools via a Javascript content-script in my extension. I simply copy the CSS file to my extension directory and it is good to go with the following code in my JS file:

```
window.onload = function() {
var link = document.createElement('link');
link.href = chrome.extension.getURL('style.css');
link.type = 'text/css';
link.rel = 'stylesheet';
link.media = 'all';
document.getElementsByTagName('HEAD')[0].appendChild(link);
}
```

This did not require me to modify the CSS after the fact or use `!important`.