# Chrome Local Overrides don't persist on refresh

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm adding local css overrides to page, and they work! But when refreshing the page the stylesheet in overrides tab still shows, but styles aren't reflected. I thought the main reason for local overrides functionality in chrome was so that those changes persist on page refresh.

I noticed that the styles are only "re-enabled" when I manually add a new style rule to the page through devtools "Styles" tab on the inspector (just pressing the "+" button, nothing specific the rule can be empty).

Some possible solutions:

- [Chrome CSS Local Overrides instead of !important for Chrome Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62973672/chrome-css-local-overrides-instead-of-important-for-chrome-extension) (but doesn't address this case specifically)
- [Local overrides in chrome – keep active while devtools are closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51522923/local-overrides-in-chrome-keep-active-while-devtools-are-closed) (seems related, no answers on this question)

(For context this featured on Chrome explained here: https://developer.chrome.com/blog/new-in-devtools-65/#overrides)

Please help!

Comment: Ever find a solution to this? Experiencing the same.

Answer (score 1):

`inspector-stylesheet` you add rules to is NOT a web resource, it's NOT on page until you add it.

Click and hold "add css rule" to select stylesheet that persists on page reload, then it'll be included on reload

Comment: Can you include more detail on "add css rule," I can't find the button anywhere. When I press and hold on "New Style Rule" button, I can select the local override, but it doesn't persist on reload.

Comment: @PhysRex that's `+` button next to the `:hov` and `.cls` next to filter of css properties of element, on the right pane of Elements tab in Chrome Devtools

Comment: Yea that's what I mentioned in my question, it loads when I use that button to select override, but doesn't persist once I reload the page.